# Some std::unique_ptr uses and "gotchas"

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, resource-management

What are some of C++11 **`std::unique_ptr`** uses and *gotchas*?

Can I use `std::unique_ptr` also to store dynamically allocated arrays?

Can I use `std::unique_ptr` also with resources using a custom deletion mechanism?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's organize some uses and gotchas using a Q&A format.

---

**Q1:** I'd like to store a *pointer* to a class `Component` inside my class `X`.
I don't want the "container" class `X` to be copyable; `X` is the only owner of `Component` instances.
I know that *owning*  *raw* pointers are a bad thing and potential sources of "leaktrocities" (instead *observing* raw pointers are fine).
What **smart pointer** could I use for this purpose?

**A1:** C++11's **`std::unique_ptr`** is certainly a good option.

It's fine in cases of **unique (non-shared) ownership**, and doesn't have the overhead of `std::shared_ptr`.
It's an excellent replacement for previous C++98/03 `boost::scoped_ptr`.
In fact, in addition, `std::unique_ptr` provides **move semantics**.
So, if class `X` contains `unique_ptr<Component>` data members (and other movable data members), the whole class `X` will be *automatically* movable.

An example use is showed below:

```
#include <memory> // for std::unique_ptr

class X
{
    std::unique_ptr<Component> m_pComponent;
    ....

public:
    X()
        : m_pComponent( new Component() )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

(Of course, being a *smart* pointer, there's no need to explicitly delete it in the containing class destructor.)

---

**Q2:** That's great! No need for explicit destructor, no `std::shared_ptr` overhead (typical C++ philosophy: *"We don't pay for things we don't use"*), move semantics machinery already implemented!
However, I have a problem: my class `Component` has a constructor overload which takes some parameter that I need to calculate in constructor code before creating `Component` instances. I tried using ordinary `operator=` assigment in constructor to assign the newly created `Component` to the `unique_ptr`, but I got an error message:

```
X::X()
{
    ....

    const int param = CalculateCoolParameter();

    // This assignment fails:
    m_pComponent = new Component(param); // <---- Error pointing to '=' here
                 ^--- error
}
```

**A2:** OK, probably you had expected an `operator=` overload releasing the previous owned
pointer (if any) and assigning to the newly created one.
Unfortunately, there isn't such an overload.
However, the **`std::unique_ptr::reset()`** method will do!

```
m_pComponent.reset( new Component(param) );
```

---

**Q3:** Hey! This `unique_ptr` is really cool!
I like the fact that it's smart, it's automatically movable, and doesn't bring overhead.
So, I'd like to use it to store a **dynamically allocated array** of some constant size (calculated at run-time) instead of using `std::vector` (in this portion of code I'm highly constrained and I don't want to pay for the `std:vector` overhead, since I don't want all the `std::vector` dynamically resizing features, deep-copy, etc.).

I tried something like this:

```
const size_t count = GetComponentsCount();
unique_ptr<Component> components( new Component[count] );
```

It compiles fine, but I noted that `~Component` destructor is called only *once*, instead I expected `count` destructor calls! What's going wrong here?

**A3:** The problem is that, with the above syntax, `std::unique_ptr` uses `delete` to release the allocated objects. But since those were allocated using `new[]`, the proper cleanup call is **`delete[]`** (not the simple `delete` without brackets).

To fix that and to instruct `unique_ptr` to properly use `delete[]` for releasing resources, the following syntax must be used:

```
unique_ptr<Component[]> components( new Components[count] ); 
//                  ^^
//
// Note brackets "[]" after the first occurrence of "Component" 
// in unique_ptr template argument.
//
```

---

**Q4:** That's great! But can I use `unique_ptr` also in cases in which the resource release code is not performed using ordinary C++ `delete` (or `delete[]`), but instead using some **custom cleanup function**, like `fclose()` for C `<stdio.h>` files (opened with `fopen()`), or `CloseHandle()` for Win32 file `HANDLE`s (created using `CreateFile()`)?

**A4:** That's definitely possible: you can specify a **custom deleter** for `std::unique_ptr`.

e.g.:

```
// 
// Custom deleter function for FILE*: fclose().
//
std::unique_ptr<FILE,          // <-- the wrapped raw pointer type: FILE*
                int(*)(FILE*)> // <-- the custom deleter type: fclose() prototype
myFile( fopen("myfile", "rb"), // <-- resource (FILE*) is returned by fopen()
        fclose );              // <-- the deleter function: fclose()



//
// Custom deleter functor for Win32 HANDLE: calls CloseHandle().
//
struct CloseHandleDeleter
{
    // The following pointer typedef is required, since
    // the raw resource is HANDLE (not HANDLE*).
    typedef HANDLE pointer;

    // Custom deleter: calls CloseHandle().
    void operator()(HANDLE handle) const
    {
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, CloseHandleDeleter> myFile( CreateFile(....) );
```

Comment: FWIW, what do you pay for the vector features you don't use? (hint: nothing)

Comment: At least from a memory footprint, `std::vector` can use 3 pointers, instead `unique_ptr` just one.

Comment: A2: a nicer solution, if possible, is to have a method doing the caluclation and returning the std::unique_ptr , then use that right in the initializer list.

Comment: @Mr.C64 But `unique_ptr<T[]>` is not usable by itself (note how you need to carry around the size on your own).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You can have _N_ arrays of the same size, and just store size once and having _N_ `unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Comment: I'm still not sold :( I can't envision a scenario where having a couple extra pointers would not be fine, but allocating all those arrays would.

Comment: If you have a matrix 10,000x10,000 with each element being a dynamically allocated array, each `vector` has 8 bytes overhead (2 additional pointers if compared to `unique_ptr`), so total overhead is 800,000,000 bytes, i.e. circa 760MB.